# How torrent work behind NAT

Tags: nat

I am behind my router.still file is uploading from my side how it's possible ;I think no one can request me;

Answer (score 1):

No one can *connect* directly to you, without a pinhole (or UPnP creating one.) However that does not mean you cannot connect to other peers who can then request data from you.